# Search webpart not giving results for subsites

Tags: 2007, web-part, search, search-results, configuration

We have a webpart to search documents that is not searching the sub-site of the site where the search webpart is placed

Any suggestion on why the webpart does not give results of the documents located on a subsite.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your search based on Scope ?
If not try create one on site collection or central admin. Add a new rule which includes a link to the subsite and check how many items it shows. Remember to include the items.

Comment: +1 You should always check central admin first!

Answer (score 0):

WHat is the depth selected in the content source, make sure that the content source setting is set to crawl everything under the given URL.